# Garbage value when getting integer value from binary file in c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am studying binary file of C++ nowadays. I made a example code for it, but it does not work well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream writeFile;
    ifstream readFile;
    int temp = 1;

    writeFile.open("file.dat", ios::binary);

    for (int i = 5; i <= 10 ; i++) // range 5 to 10
        writeFile.write((char*)(&i), sizeof(i));

    writeFile.close();

    readFile.open("file.dat", ios::binary);
    readFile.seekg(0);
    while (!readFile.eof()) {
        readFile.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(temp));
        cout << "temp: " << temp << endl;
        readFile >> ws;
    }
    readFile.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
temp: 5
temp: 6
temp: 7
temp: 8
temp: 167772160
temp: 167772160
```

When I change the range not to include 9 (for example, 5 to 8), it works well. Also, When I make the same code with double type, it works well. So I think the integer 9 is problem. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 4):

`readFile >> ws;` discards white space, which is non-sense for a binary stream. In this case, the character value 9 (which is `'\t'`) is skipped, corrupting your stream. Simply remove that line.

The second problem is you are not checking the state of the stream between reading and displaying the value. EOF is only detected *after* a read would exceed the end of the file. This is why you get your invalid value twice, the second time the read fails and simply leaves `temp` with it's previous value. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for a more details.

Comment: The value 9 is actually `\t`. 10 is `\n`. The fact that both are considered white space is what causes the issue.

Comment: Or rather, `readFile >> ws` skips over the `\t` character only, then reading the four bytes `00 00 00 0a`, interpreted as a little-endian 4-byte integer is the value 167772160. This is still well defined (I believe). However, the next read attempt reads beyond the EOF. That is UB, and displaying 167772160 is a valid form of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by François Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42539834/434551) already has the answer to the question of why your code behaves the way it does.

Here are couple of methods to fix the problem.

1. Use a `for` loop to read the numbers. It mirrors the loop used to write to it.

   ```
   readFile.open("file.dat", ios::binary);
   for (int i = 5; i <= 10 ; i++)
   {
      readFile.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(temp));
      cout << "temp: " << temp << endl;
   }
   readFile.close();
   ```
2. Use the `while` loop correctly.

   ```
   readFile.open("file.dat", ios::binary);
   while (readFile.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(temp)))
   {
      cout << "temp: " << temp << endl;
   }
   readFile.close();
   ```